# How to print to the terminal if there is no flag present

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

so in my code its structured like this

```
USAGE="Usage: ./MyProject.sh [-o <output-file>] <guests>"
```

Where -o is a flag option that allows us to print in the file name of names of guests.
For instance i insert this into the terminal

Example 1

```
./MyProject.sh -o GuestNames list
```

The program should create a file called GuestNames and store whatever is in the file name in list into GuestNames. IF however, I input this following command

Example 2:

```
./MyProject.sh -o list
```

It should just print the following names of people in the list into the terminal.

I already have the code down (like it can detect file name list, etc.) , What i'm having trouble with is printing it out of the terminal if there is no flag present as seen on example 2.

Here is my code:

```
outfile=  #default: print to stdout
function user{
while getopts ":o:" arg; do
case $arg in
 o) outfile=$OPTARG #tests the outfile to see if there is a flag
  ;;
 #Other cases and more code below but won't effect anything
}

if ( outfile= $OPTARG); then
$OPTARG > $outfile
print_guests >$outfile #added for the guests to be print
else
print_guests #function that converts the list into an array and prints out guests
fi
```

The error i get is "$outfile: ambiguous redirect" since i think its trying to direct the outfield into an empty string and not trying to print out to the terminal. If you can please help me i'll appreciate it!

Comment: Wow how dumb of me, thank you for that

Comment: General rule of thumb when you first hit a problem in a bash script, place set -xv at the top of the script (after the shebang) and you will get information on what variables are set and which commands are being executed.  You could also use shellcheck.net to check your script, as there are errors in what you presented outside the problem you were having :)

Answer (score 0):

So, you are using the global variable `outfile` to store the path to the file that you are writing to. The way that you are using getopts appears to be mostly correct, you just need to use a more appropriate test to determine whether to write to stdout or to a file. Here's an example:

```
outfile=  #default: print to stdout
function parse_args {
    while getopts ":o:" arg; do
       case $arg in
           o) outfile=$OPTARG
           ;;
       esac
    done
}

parse_args "$@"

if [ -n "$outfile" ]; then
    print_guests > "$outfile" #added for the guests to be print
else
    print_guests
fi
```

It's also important to make sure that you use `"$@"` to pass the script arguments to your argument parsing function.

Comment: Rather than having two different lines that call print_guests, you might consider: `if [ -n "$outfile" ]; then exec > "$outfile"; fi; print_guests`, or something like `if [ -z "$outfile" ]; then outfile=/dev/stdout; fi; print_guests` (the first is better).

Comment: Good point. moving around my file descriptors is something I tend to avoid doing unless it's inside a subshell.